# fputcsv adds unwanted Validation comment at top of file

Tags: php, validation, csv, comments, fputcsv

I need csv output with column headers and comma delimited data. The `fputcsv` function is working right except that it places a "Validation" comment at the top of the output file:

```
<!-- Validated at 2016-04-17 00:32:00 -->
```

This line causes the file to fail when updating my data. If I remove the comment, the file works. Does anyone know how to generate `fputcsv` output without the comment line?

Here is code

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=gmail.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

fputcsv($output, array('Name', 'Given Name', 'Family Name', 'Group Membership', 'E-mail 1 - Value'));

// Connect to host and open db
include('includes/connect.php');

//Set Date range. Determines current renewal year for Select statement
$year = date('Y') - 1;
$group = date('Y')." member";

/* Select specified member data  */
$sql = "SELECT firstLast, firstName, lastName, email, status, gmail, payDate
FROM membership, memberDues
WHERE payDate >= '$year-10-01' AND ID = memberID
ORDER BY lastName, firstName";

$result = mysqli_query($dbCnx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$gmailArray = array( $row['firstLast'], $row['firstName'], $row['lastName'], "$group", $row['email'] ); 

fputcsv($output, $gmailArray);}
```

Comment: `fputcsv` doesn't have that functionality, do you mind posting your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. My security include (which I hadn't looked at in a few years), inserts that Validation line if user has permission to view the page. I guess it's useful to review old bits of plug&play code every so often to help trouble shoot these types of annoyances.